# Anaconda linux install: conda: command not found

Tags: python, linux, bash, anaconda

So I installed Anaconda for Python 3.6 according to the instruction from the official [downloads](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) page and also [this](http://linuxpitstop.com/install-anaconda-miniconda-conda-on-ubuntu-centos-linux/).

I followed all the steps and when I was asked if I wanted to add the Anaconda3 install location to my `bashrc` I said yes. When I print out the contents of that file, I have:

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
   . /etc/bashrc
fi

# added by Anaconda 2.3.0 installer
export PATH="/home/username/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

# added by Anaconda3 4.3.1 installer
export PATH="/home/username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

So obviously, it's been added. However, when I run `conda -V`, I get:

> bash: conda: commmand not found...

What else can be causing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to source the file, or open a new terminal instance, in order for the configuration to be applied:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Small error was driving me crazy. Will be accepting in 8 minutes. :)